# A question which depends on monotone and Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a, b]\rightarrow [a, b]$ be a continuous and strictly increasing function. Suppose $f'(x)=0$ almost everywhere. Q: Does $f$ satisfy a Lipschitz condition?

Comment: Does $f'$ exist everywhere?

Comment: @copper.hat. Yes. Since $f$ is increasing  it implies the Lebesgues' theorem.

Comment: Lebesgue's theorem yields almost everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ satisfied a Lipschitz condition it would be absolutely continuous and $f(x) = f(a)+\int_a^x f'(t) dt$, but since $f'(x) = 0$ ae. $x$, we have $f(x) = f(a)$ which contradicts it being strictly increasing.

So no, it cannot satisfy a Lipschitz condition.

Comment: You are very welcome, glad to be of help.